# x-loader code is not very clear

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, boot, u-boot

Hi all I am new to stackoverflow
I have been looking into x-loader code in my project and tried to port an existing running x-loader to a different chip (that is almost same just some gpios changed).
    But I am getting few problems in understanding the x-loader and u-boot program flow and requirement of these lines
this are the lines from lib/board.c

```
if ((get_mem_type() == MMC_ONENAND) || (get_mem_type() == MMC_NAND)){
        // First Try for NAND Boot
        for (i = NAND_UBOOT_START; i < NAND_UBOOT_END; i+= NAND_BLOCK_SIZE){
            if (!nand_read_block(buf, i))
                buf += NAND_BLOCK_SIZE; /* advance buf ptr */
        }
        fio_pbias_init();
        if( *((int *)CFG_LOADADDR) != 0xEA000012 ){
            printf("NAND Does not have U-boot\n");
            buf = (uchar*) CFG_LOADADDR;
            buf += mmc_boot(buf);
        }
    }
```

1. What is MMC_ONENAND, i googled but it tells it is also a nand, then why is another MMC_NAND
2. What are these macros

   ```
               NAND_UBOOT_START=0x0080000
               NAND_UBOOT_END=0x0100000
   ```

   Why we are checking about u-boot in x-loader, shouldn't it complete task for x-loader first.
3. can somebody explain this nand_block_read in layman terms, I am not good with memory allocation and stuff, because I can't understand why only this address!!
4. What is the purpose of this check

   ```
          if( *((int *)CFG_LOADADDR) != 0xEA000012 )
   ```

here  CFG_LOADADDR=0x80008000

I have done some research into all these but as like always things are so perfectly written that i can not make any sense.
Maybe these are very basic or stupid questions but I am also very new to this. I need to know things in layman terms, as why we need these things as the way they are in actual source.
P.S As I compiled the code I get some errors at run time from this function

```
             omap_enable_hwecc_bch4(buf, &ecc_calc[0]);
```

This is in a driver. I searched it and it says to report errors in NAND memory. What that supposed to mean, as the same code run flawless with previous chip without any errors.

Comment: What part are you trying to port U-Boot to?

Comment: *As I compiled the code I get some errors at run time from this function* **What does that mean?** Was it when you compiled, or was it at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

> What is MMC_ONENAND, i googled but it tells it is also a nand, then
>   why is another MMC_NAND

It is another type of NAND memory which has to be configured differently from MMC_NAND.

> What are these macros
>
> ```
>             NAND_UBOOT_START=0x0080000
>             NAND_UBOOT_END=0x0100000
> ```
>
> Why we are checking about u-boot in x-loader, shouldn't it complete task for x-loader first.

These define the address range in NAND memory to be searched for U-Boot; starting U-Boot is a task of X-Loader, so it's no wonder that X-Loader has to check where U-Boot sits.

> can somebody explain this nand_block_read in layman terms, I am not
>   good with memory allocation and stuff, because I can't understand why
>   only this address!!

I think you mean `nand_read_block`:

```
/* read a block data to buf
 * return 1 if the block is bad or ECC error can't be corrected for any page
 * return 0 on sucess
 */ 
int nand_read_block(unsigned char *buf, ulong block_addr)
```

No memory allocation takes place here; the memory pointed to by `buf` starts at `CFG_LOADADDR`.

> What is the purpose of this check
>
> ```
>    if( *((int *)CFG_LOADADDR) != 0xEA000012 )
> ```
>
> here CFG_LOADADDR=0x80008000

This compares the 4-byte-word (presumably `sizeof (int)` is 4) at the start of the loaded blocks with the value `0xEA000012`. Apparently this is to check whether valid U-Boot code blocks have been read into memory - on an ARM CPU, `0xEA000012` is a branch opcode.